# Efeito pós digitação no placeholder

Tags: css, html5

Pessoal estou tentando adicionar um comportamento em um placeholder mas não estou conseguindo.

No site do [ingresso.com](https://wwws.ingresso.com/cliente/?_ga=1.260507277.1048009740.1439504341#/login) quando o usuário digita um valor no forml placeholder some e aparece um pequeno label acima do texto digitado.

Esse tipo de efeito é um comportamento do placeholder via CSS ou é um comportamento em conjunto com outros componentes?

Para implementar isso, o que devo alterar no CSS?

Answer (score 4):

olha, infelizmente não existe um `pseudo-seletor` para o `input` que sinalize que ele tenha um valor vazio ou não, então se ouve-se um `pseudo-seletor` `:empty` eu poderia lhe dá uma resposta completa.

Porem podemos usar outros `pseudo-seletores` para conseguimos um resultado aproximado, no caso temos o `:valid` e `:invalid`, caso possa usar a propriedade `required` ou `pattern` nos inputs, porem isto pode impedir o envio de um form caso algum input não seja preenchido:

```css
.float-label {
  position: relative;
  height: 37px;
  width: 200px;
}

.float-label label,
.float-label input {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.float-label label {
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
  left: 2px;
  top: 18px;
  color: gainsboro;
}

.float-label input {
  top: 17px;
}

.float-label input:valid + label {
  top: 0px;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<form src="#">
  <div class="float-label">    
    <input id="teste" type="text" required />
    <label for="teste">Teste</label>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Simular Envio" />
</form>
```

Uma segunda opção é o `pseudo-seletor` `:focus`, isto fará que o label suba quando o usuário entrar no `input`, porem o label irá retornar assim que o input perder o `focus`.

```css
.float-label {
  position: relative;
  height: 37px;
  width: 200px;
}

.float-label label,
.float-label input {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.float-label label {
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
  left: 2px;
  top: 18px;
  color: gainsboro;
}

.float-label input {
  top: 17px;
}

.float-label input:focus + label {
  top: 0px;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<form src="#">
  <div class="float-label">    
    <input id="teste" type="text" />
    <label for="teste">Teste</label>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Simular Envio" />
</form>
```

Então ao meu ver só resta uma opção, usar um `data-custom` que informe que o input está vazio, para tal você vai precisar de um pequeno JS.

```js
var floatLabel = document.querySelectorAll(".float-label");
var onFloatLabelChange = function () {
  if (this.value.length == 0) {
    this.dataset.empty = null;
  } else {
    delete this.dataset.empty;
  }
}

floatLabel = [].slice.apply(floatLabel);
floatLabel.forEach(function (container) {
  var input = container.querySelector("input");
  input.addEventListener("keyup", onFloatLabelChange);
});
```

```css
.float-label {
  position: relative;
  height: 37px;
  width: 200px;
}

.float-label label,
.float-label input {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.float-label label {
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
  left: 2px;
  top: 0px;    
  color: black;
}

.float-label input {
  top: 17px;
}

.float-label input[data-empty] + label {
  top: 18px;
  color: gainsboro;
}
```

```html
<form src="#">
  <div class="float-label">    
    <input id="teste" type="text" data-empty />
    <label for="teste">Teste</label>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Simular Envio" />
</form>
```